# error using image2D in compute shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, textures, shader

I want to do some calculations with a compute shader, and write the results into an image. [Here is a tutorial](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//browser/OpenSceneGraph/trunk/examples/osgcomputeshaders/osgcomputeshaders.cpp?rev=13311), which I wanted to follow (I use OpenSceneGraph in my project).

But the shader code does not compile. In the tutorial the image is passed like a uniform, but after some research I have found, that you should pass it in a layout. I changed that part in my code, but it still do not work, and I receive an error, when I want to use the image.

Here is my simple compute shader:

```
#version 430
#define TILE_SIZE 1
layout(local_size_x = TILE_SIZE, local_size_y = TILE_SIZE, local_size_z = 1) in;
layout (binding = 1, rgba32f) writeonly uniform  image2D targetTex;
void main() {
imageStore(targetTex, gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy, vec4(1, 0, 1, 0));
}
```

And my error message:

```
error C1115: unable to find compatible overloaded function "imageStore(struct image2D1x32_bindless, uvec2, vec4)"
```

It seems like the format of the image would be wrong, but I have no idea, where is my mistake.

Comment: Try to cast `gl_GlobalInvocationID.xy` into a `ivec2`

Comment: I think @pleluron is right. `gl_GlobalInvocationID` is a `uvec3`, while the second argument to `imageStore()` is a `ivec2`. The error message pretty much tells you that.

Comment: Omg, thanks! I was sure, that the image causes the problem, and I did not notice the other parts of the error message